# My Select query is not working in Spring MVC 3 using MySql Database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, spring-3

My DAO Class:

```
public boolean RetreiveId(UserBean userBean){
    boolean userExists = false;

    /* Provide table name and column name carefully in the sql query below.
     * here i have a table "userbean" with two column's
     * "userId" and "password" both of varchar2 type.
     */
             String sql1 = "select userId from userbean "+"where userId = ?";
 jdbcTemplate.update(sql1, new Object[] { userBean.getUserId()});
                            System.out.println("^^^^^^^^^^sql1"+sql1);
            int rowcount=1;
          if(rowcount==1){
        userExists = true;
    }
    return userExists;
}
}
```

MyController Class

```
@RequestMapping("/RetreiveId")
public ModelAndView RetreiveId(@ModelAttribute @Valid UserBean      userBean,BindingResult result,HttpSession session){
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("loginLatest");

    //if input bean does not have validation error then proceed
    if(!result.hasFieldErrors()){
        //if not a valid user then add error
        //else proceed to user welcome page


                       if(!combatService.RetreiveId(userBean)){
            result.addError(new ObjectError("err", "Invalid Credentials"));
        }
//          if(!combatService.RegisterUser(userBean)){
//              result.addError(new ObjectError("err", "Invalid Credentials"));
//          }
//          else{
//                            session.setAttribute("Sess_Var", userBean.getUserId());
////                             view.addObject("Sess_Var", userBean.getUserId());
//              view.setViewName("welcome");
//          }

                       else{
//                            session.setAttribute("Sess_Var", userBean.getUserId());
//                             view.addObject("Sess_Var", userBean.getUserId());
            view.setViewName("loginLatest");
                       }
    }
```

It is not working, it is giving error, Insert Query is working well but I want to retrieve the password of a particular username

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is     
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL      
[select userId from userbean where userId = ?]; Can not issue executeUpdate() for   
SELECTs; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue executeUpdate() for     
SELECTs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line cause problem:

> jdbcTemplate.update(sql1, new Object[] { userBean.getUserId()});

You are trying to pass select statement into method which can only execute insert, delete or update statement.
[jdbcTemplete.update Doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

Switch to queryForObject method.

I think it should help:

```
public boolean RetreiveId(UserBean userBean){
     boolean userExists = false;

/* Provide table name and column name carefully in the sql query below.
 * here i have a table "userbean" with two column's
 * "userId" and "password" both of varchar2 type.
 */
     String sql1 = "select userId from userbean "+"where userId = ?";
     UserBean ub = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql1, 
              new Object[] { userBean.getUserId()});
     System.out.println("^^^^^^^^^^sql1"+sql1);

     if (ub != null) {
          userExists = true;
     }
     return userExists;
     }
```

}

Comment: jdbcTemplate.execute(sql1, new Object[] { userBean.getUserId()});     Error is   "No Suitable method found for execute(String,Object[])"

Comment: Sir please tell me the error and what to do?  bcoz i have to use this to retrieve the values of username entered by user "new Object[] { userBean.getUserId()}"

Comment: Can Anyone Tell me the solution ? Please help me out?

Comment: Here is an example [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/).

Answer (score 1):

I think here the problem is with `jdbcTemplate.update`. Try `jdbcTemplate.execute`. 
I hope it will work.

`jdbcTemplate.execute` is JDBC data access operation. [more info](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html)

`jdbcTemplate.update` is update operation (such as an insert, update or delete statement). [more info](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my Question is

```
String sql1 = "select password from userbean where userId = ?";
String name = (String)jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
        sql1, new Object[] { userBean.getUserId() }, String.class);
```

And Name Variable will contain the Password.
Thanks a lot Everyone.